# How to hide the logs of PHPMailer?

Tags: php, server, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

My code works but when I send an Email I see this long block on informations that starts like this:

> 2021-03-06 13:42:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
> 2021-03-06 13:42:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
> 2021-03-06 13:42:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
> 2021-03-06 13:42:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
> 2021-03-06 13:42:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
> 2021-03-06 13:42:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]

...and goes on writing al the informations about PHPMailer.

I don't want everyone to see it after they send an Email, how can I hide it?

that's my code:

```
if($errore == 0){
  $message_email = 'Messaggio inviato da: '.$name.' '.$surname.'<br>';
  $message_email .= 'Email: '.$email.'<br>';
  $message_email .= 'Telefono: '.$number.'<br>';
  $message_email .= 'Oggetto: '.$object.'<br>';
  $message_email .= 'Corpo: '.$message.'<br>';
  require 'PHPMailer.php';
  require 'Exception.php';
  require 'SMTP.php';
  

  $mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;  
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Port       = 587;
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Username   = "myemail@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password   = "mypass";
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->setFrom('bibibibi@gmail.com');
  $mail->addAddress('lalala@gmail.com');
  $mail->msgHtml($messaggio_email);
  $mail->Subject = $object;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "something went wrong";
  var_dump($mail);
} else {
  echo 'Email sent';
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Do you still have `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;` ?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean, I wrote $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; as you can see I added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the "SMTP class debug output mode." using the `SMTPDebug` property.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
```

Your actual value (`1`) corresponding to `DEBUG_CLIENT`.

But you should use one of  the following allowed values :

- SMTP::DEBUG_OFF: No output
- SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT: Client messages
- SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER: Client and server messages
- SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION: As SERVER plus connection status
- SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL: Noisy, low-level data output, rarely needed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put any of following codes in the try { } block to make it work.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
```

OR

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
```

Comment: Presumably, the `SMTP::DEBUG_OFF` is defined with the value of `0`, so these two code snippets are effectively the same. Also, this has also been mentioned in the other answer.